# Automated ssh-copy-id for a non-root user using expect

Tags: ssh, sh, expect

I'm a newbie to Linux, Bash and Expect

I'm currently working on a script which automatizes the ssh-keygen and ssh-copy-id processes

This is the wanted behavior:

- Create SSH keys from root, for a non-root user( the rsa one )
- Copying them on a given remote server
- By SSH, ssh-copy-id the remote-host's keys back to the non-root user

Basically, to create a password-less ssh connection between them, all automatized on the main server.

I'd like to avoid the "su nagios" command, because it will interrupt the script waiting for a command ( or if it's not true, help me to use it correctly ).

The expect script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set user [lindex $argv 0]
set server [lindex $argv 1]

send_user $user
send_user $server

spawn ssh-copy-id $user@$server
expect {
    "(yes/no)? " {
        send "yes\r"
        exp_continue
    }
    "password: " {
        send "nagios\r"
        send_user "\n"
    }
}

expect "$ "
spawn ssh -v $user@$server "ssh-copy-id nagios@192.168.174.142"
expect {
    "(yes/no)? " {
        send "yes\r"
        exp_continue
    }
    "password: " {
        send "nagios\r"
        send_user "\n"
    }
}
expect "$ "
exit
```

What I'm trying to do:

to create the keys in the right folder:

```
 ssh-keygen -t rsa -N "" -f /home/nagios/.ssh/id_rsa
```

to change the text regarding user and domain

```
sed -i s/"root@localhost.localdomain"/"nagios@localhost.localdomain"/g /home/nagios/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

then I just copy them for the ssh-copy-id command..

```
cp -Rfv /home/nagios/.ssh/id_rsa /root/.ssh/
cp -Rfv /home/nagios/.ssh/id_rsa.pub /root/.ssh/
```

- Are the keys generated binded to the user who created them?
- Is that "root@localhost.localdomain" just a "comment" as I've read while browsing on internet?
- Is there a way to use ssh-copy-id from root for the non-root user?

Errors I'm facing :

```
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: Host key verification failed.

expect: spawn id exp5 not open
while executing
"expect "$ ""
    (file "./copyRemoteKeys.sh" line 36)
```

May someone help me to debug, fix, or even help me to understand better how these things works?

Comment: Once you send the password to ssh-copy-id, it will do its work and finish. Change `expect "$ "` to `expect eof`

Comment: Thank you! It worked fine for the expect script's error (:
Unfortunately it's still giving me the Host key verification failed error.
Any clue on how to fix that?